# ThreeJS not rendering anything

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to do a simple 'Hello World' using ThreeJS and Angular 2, but I cannot get it to do anything. I've checked my code and couldn't find anything wrong with it...

Here's the Typescript code.

```
`https://pastebin.com/hN50e5FR`
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to add Renderer's doom to document.

```
containerDiv.appendChild( this.renderer.domElement );
```

Comment: Hey! While that works, can I use an existing canvas instead of adding another one?

Comment: sure check [here.](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/renderers/WebGLRenderer)  
or try this
new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { canvas: myCanvas } );